# Rect Module Python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, contour, rect

I have recently downloaded some code in python that tries to scan a receipt(or prepare for scanning). I tried to run the code, but there seems to be a problem. Python doesn't recognize the module 'Rect'. I tried to download the module, but there is no such module available. I'm stuck and am wondering what to do.

Note: Only one line of code uses the module

Code :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import rect

# add image here.
image = cv2.imread('test_pic.jpg')

# resize image
# choose optimal dimensions
image = cv2.resize(image, (1500, 880))

# create copy of original image
orig = image.copy()

# convert to grayscale and blur to smooth
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# gaussian blur to smoothen texture
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
#blurred = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 5)

# apply Canny Edge Detection
edged = cv2.Canny(blurred, 0, 50)
orig_edged = edged.copy()

# find the contours in the edged image
# keep only the largest ones, and
# initialize screen contour
(contours, _) = cv2.findContours(edged, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
contours = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)

#x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contours[0])
#cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),0)

# get approximate contour
for c in contours:
    p = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * p, True)

    if len(approx) == 4:
        target = approx
        break


# map target points to 800x800 quadrilateral
approx = rect.rectify(target)
pts2 = np.float32([[0,0],[800,0],[800,800],[0,800]])

M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(approx,pts2)
dst = cv2.warpPerspective(orig,M,(800,800))

cv2.drawContours(image, [target], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
dst = cv2.cvtColor(dst, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


# use thresholding on warped image to get scanned effect (If Required)
ret,th1 = cv2.threshold(dst,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
th2 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(dst,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,\
            cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
th3 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(dst,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,\
            cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
ret2,th4 = cv2.threshold(dst,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# show results
cv2.imshow("Original.jpg", orig)
cv2.imshow("Original Gray.jpg", gray)
cv2.imshow("Original Blurred.jpg", blurred)
cv2.imshow("Original Edged.jpg", orig_edged)
cv2.imshow("Outline.jpg", image)
cv2.imshow("Thresh Binary.jpg", th1)
cv2.imshow("Thresh mean.jpg", th2)
cv2.imshow("Thresh gauss.jpg", th3)
cv2.imshow("Otsu's.jpg", th4)
cv2.imshow("dst.jpg", dst)

# other thresholding methods
"""
ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(dst,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
ret,thresh2 = cv2.threshold(dst,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
ret,thresh3 = cv2.threshold(dst,127,255,cv2.THRESH_TRUNC)
ret,thresh4 = cv2.threshold(dst,127,255,cv2.THRESH_TOZERO)
ret,thresh5 = cv2.threshold(dst,127,255,cv2.THRESH_TOZERO_INV)

cv2.imshow("Thresh Binary", thresh1)
cv2.imshow("Thresh Binary_INV", thresh2)
cv2.imshow("Thresh Trunch", thresh3)
cv2.imshow("Thresh TOZERO", thresh4)
cv2.imshow("Thresh TOZERO_INV", thresh5)
"""

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [github repo](https://github.com/ayushchopra96/PythonCamScanner) you presumably grabbed the code from, there's another file called `rect.py` with a single function `rectify()` that is used in the main program. In Python, if you create other `.py` modules, you can import them into your code for better encapsulation of certain functions, although it seems really unnecessary in this code to keep the `rectify()` function in a different file altogether. Something that's equally basic but more common is a `.py` file with all your functions, and then a main `.py` file which uses those functions.

Edit: so to be clear, the `rect` module is in the repo itself. A word of advice, generally clone a whole repo unless you know *for sure* that you don't need the other files in it.

Comment: I'm having a hard time following the code. Dst is the image I want to use for tesseract right?

Comment: Also it happened to be that the repository I cloned from only contained two files not the rect one.

Comment: I see, I just searched for the text from the code and found that repo. Might be better to open a separate question. Do look through the documentation of the functions on OpenCV's website though.